# Delete a name in A sheet deletes the same name in B Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a roster in A sheet and in B sheet I have the positions I need to run my company.
Every name in A sheet will be in B but not in the same order, I want some help so that if someone left the company I will delete his name in the roster A sheet and I want the same name to be deleted in B sheet. I want only name to be deleted not the position he is assigned to.

```
A sheet          B Sheet
Name Hire date   Name  Position
John 10/17/2016  Sam  Sales Manager
Paul 10/18/2016  Paul Inventory Manager
Sam  10/16/2016  John Clerk
```

Name and Hire Date are in Sheet A and Name and Position are in Sheet B.So if I delete the John row in A sheet, I want to able to delete John in B sheet but leave the position on it.

Comment: And I hope you never have the same names several times in same time... Perhaps better works with an Id

Comment: Yeah but I have same name once in the B sheet

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea as to how to go about it - however, as YannickIngenierie suggests, it might be better to have a unique ID for each person, in the event of name duplication:

```
Sub removeEmployee()
Dim r as Range, s As String, c As Range

s = InputBox("Enter name to remove")
If Len(Trim(s)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A") 'search name
  Set r = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
  Set c = r.Find(s, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
  If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete 'remove entry
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B")
  Set r = .Range("a2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
  Set c = r.Find(s, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
  If Not c Is Nothing Then c.ClearContents 'remove name,retain position
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If this works for you, would you mind checking it as answered, please?  Thank you.

Comment: Hey @DaveU, for some reason the code is not working for me. Even though I input the name in the message box, nothing happening.

Comment: Hard for me to know what's happening without seeing your code.  Did you try stepping through it?